# What happens if a 12 V, 7 Ah battery is installed instead of a 12 V, 4 Ah battery in the Schneider APC PRO550?

Tags: power-supply, power, batteries, ups

I have UPS APC Pro 550 and need to change its battery. Its battery has a capacity of 21W @ 15 min-rate to 1.67 V per cell @ 25°C (77F), and what I found in local market is 7 Ah and 9 Ah.

First, I need to know 21 W @ 15 min, etc. means what Ah?

Second, what are the consequences if a higher or lower capacity battery is installed?

Comment: When you say "15 min-rate", what do you mean by that? Is that a C rating?

Comment: Bigger is better for capacity but longevity from sulphation depends on quality and if pulse charging is used to desulphate. Also read Peukert’s Law.

Comment: @hearth this description written on original battery to describe its capacity
 ( 21W @ 15 min-rate to 1.67V per cell @25°C (77°F))

Comment: @MohammedFathy That's not a systematic marking that I'm aware of; is this translated from another language by chance?

Comment: @Hearth no it's not translated from another language by chance , it's written on battery brand CSB , HR1221WF2

Comment: @Hearth please check Below link for datasheet 
https://www.csb-battery.com.tw/upfiles/dow01581489889.pdf

Comment: @MohammedFathy I'm afraid I have no idea what that means, then. It may be some standard specification that I'm not familiar with, or it may be something nonstandard that this manufacturer uses to make the numbers look bigger.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 many thanks for your help Peukert’s Law will help me

Comment: Also considering adding a 1W pulse  flyback charger for life extension

Comment: @Hearth i see ,some companies do that to complicate it's products

Answer (score 3):

The UPS will last longer before the battery runs out.

It might mis-report things like remaining time before the battery runs out or something, because it's expecting a battery of one capacity and you give it a higher capacity, but it will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The dirty way of finding out: the UPS APC Pro 550 takes an [APC RBC110](https://www.apc.com/shop/uk/en/products/APC-Replacement-Battery-Cartridge-110/P-APCRBC110) replacement battery (you should check this); if you google around a bit for "APC RBC110 alternative" you will find a lot of cheaper alternatives, all 12V and all about 7 to 9 Ah. Higher capacity is OK, see other answer.